# Different navigation bar style in different controllers?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I've got a question about setting different styles of the navigationbar in different UIViewControllers. I've got 4 different controllers and I want the last one to be totally transparent with white navigationitems and the other one to be white with black navigationitems.

Is there an quick and easy solution for this? I am thinking about setting the style for each view in the appdelegate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is save the navigation bar `tintColor` and `barTintColor` before the view appears and change it to whatever you need. Then when the view disappears, restore the previous ones.

```
@interface MyViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIColor *navigationBarTintColor;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIColor *navigationTintColor;

@end

@implementation MyViewController

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    // Save current colors
    self.navigationBarTintColor = self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor; // Background color
    self.navigationTintColor = self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor; // Items color


    self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.shadowImage = [UIImage new];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    // Get previous colors and set them
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = self.navigationBarTintColor;
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = self.navigationTintColor;
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:nil forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
}
```

EDIT: Only use this code in the view controller that needs to have a transparent navigation bar.

Comment: It looks like there's some problem. First it says it's "No visible interface for 'UITableViewController' declares the selector 'viewWillDisappear'". The second problem is, when I'm pushing back from the fourth controller wich has the transparent background the upcoming controller has also change to it. Even if set your code in all the controllers! Cant find why.. @jbouaziz

Comment: @MartinBorstrand My bad, I just edited my code. I tested it and it works fine now for me.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you so much, one tiny question about it then.. The border bottom-line in that transparant navbar, is it possible to get rid of that one in just that View Controller to? @jbouaziz

Comment: @MartinBorstrand Can you try this? `self.navigationController.navigationBar.shadowImage = [UIImage new];`